# Eglot send diagnostic information from eldoc mini buffer to be displayed by corfu or corfu-doc?

Tags: minibuffer, eldoc, eglot

Hi I am using Emacs29 with native support for Eglot, together with `corfu`, `corfu-doc` and `orderless` packages.

I was wondering if it is possible to send the documentation under point information, which I think is displayed in the mini buffer using `eldoc-doc-buffer`. To something like corfu or corfu-doc, that displays the information in a popup where the cursor is and properly formats the text. And not escaped output from the css language server

```
Shorthand property to set values for the thickness of the margin area. If left is omitted, it is the same as right. If bottom is omitted it is the same as top, if right is omitted it is the same as top. Negative values for margin properties are allowed, but there may be implementation-specific limits.

Syntax: [ <length> | <percentage> | auto ]{1,4}

MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/margin
```

or as with the TypeScript language server markdown code block

````
```typescript 
var console: Console```
````

It is kind of hard to read.

Comment: Isn't corfu something to do with completion?  Is there a connection?

Comment: The `eldoc-box` package from MELPA might be of interest.  Note also the `eldoc-box-eglot-help-at-point` command, which might be of particular interest in conjunction with `(add-to-list 'eglot-stay-out-of 'eldoc)` if you only want the info on demand.

Comment: `eldoc-box` look really interesting. I will take that for a spin. Thanks.